# Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap al intentar ejecutar paquete DTS desde C#

Tags: c#, net, ssis

Tengo un paquete .dtsx el cual quiero ejecutar desde una aplicación de consola .NET 6.
Este es el servicio instalado:

Al ejecutarlo desde Visual Studio 2012 se ejecuta correctamente pero desde la aplicación falla.

[image: Servicio SSIS]

En mi código utilizo Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
Y en el proyecto hago referencia a la dll Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll

```
Application app = new Application();
Package package = package = app.LoadPackage(DTSPath + DTSName+".dtsx", null);
```

En el código obtengo un error al intentar levantar el paquete:

[image: Error en consola]

He intentado compilar la aplicación en x64, en x32, en anycpu, intenté compilando para cada arquitectura haciendo referencia a diferentes versiones de Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll (9, 11, 16)

He intentado con diferentes instaladores de sql server y ninguno me muestra features para SSIS.

Intenté agregando con gacutil las dll y tampoco.

La carpeta del servidor donde debe correr la aplicación muestra todas estas versiones:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si me pueden ayudar a solucionarlo lo agradecería mucho.